# Why is TensorFlow Lite slower than TensorFlow on desktop?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently working on Single Image Superresolution and I've managed to freeze an existing checkpoint file and convert it into tensorflow lite. However, when performing inference using the .tflite file, the time taken to upsample one image is at least 4 times that when restoring the model using the .ckpt file.

Inference using the .ckpt file is done using session.run(), while inference using the .tflite file is done using interpreter.invoke(). Both operations were done on a Ubuntu 18 VM running on a typical PC.

What I did to find out more about the issue is to run `top` in a seperate terminal to see the CPU utilization rate when either operations are performed. Utilization rate hits 270% with the .ckpt file, but stays at around 100% with the .tflite file.

```
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_image_reshaped)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], input_bicubic_image_reshaped)
start = time.time()
interpreter.invoke()
end = time.time()
```

vs

```
y = self.sess.run(self.y_, feed_dict={self.x: image.reshape(1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], ch), self.x2: bicubic_image.reshape(1, self.scale * image.shape[0], self.scale * image.shape[1], ch), self.dropout: 1.0, self.is_training: 0})
```

One hypothesis is that tensorflow lite is not configured for multithreading, and another is that tensorflow lite is optimized for ARM processors (rather than an Intel one that my computer runs on) and thus it is slower. However, I cannot tell for sure and neither do I know how to trace the root of the issue - hopefully someone out there will be more knowledgeable about this?

Comment: On the "tensorflow lite is optimized for ARM processors" - I think that's not the issue - as I am currently observing tflite running 4x slower than tensorflow on a M1 Macbook Air (arm64 processor)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, the current TensorFlow Lite op kernels are optimized for ARM processor (using NEON instruction set). 
If SSE is available, it will try to use [NEON_2_SSE](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/80e29253740b251d7632f613ceb414205248ce93/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/common.h#L42) to adapt NEON calls to SSE, so it should be still running with some sort of SIMD. However we didn't put much effort to optimize this code path.

Regarding number of threads. There is a [SetNumThreads](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/80e29253740b251d7632f613ceb414205248ce93/tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h#L333) function in C++ API, but it's not exposed in Python API (yet). When it's not set, the underlying implementation may try to probe number of available cores. If you build the code by yourself, you can try to change the value and see if it affects the result.

Hope these helps.

Comment: Yes these helped a lot, thank you for answering the question so comprehensively!

Comment: Could you share your experience if SSD Mobilenet is realtime on averagely powerful Android devices or not i.e, in how many FPS it can run (after using tflite version)? I an unable to find this information and hence, I am not sure if it would be right to invest time to make such object detection applications for Android which require real-time response.

Comment: @hafiz031 not the answerer, but from what I've found so far SSD Mobilenet will run at around 2 to 3 FPS on an average Android device with a 224x224 input. You can double check that using the example app provided by Google as well! https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/README.md

Comment: I'm observing that tflite is running 4x slower than tensorflow even on the arm64 processor of the M1 Macbook Air - is this expected?